# Scrapy request response within a for loop gets only one value

Tags: python, scrapy

```
    for sel in name:
        self.counter += 1
        sel = "https://www.amazon.co.uk"+sel
        request = scrapy.Request(sel, callback=self.seller_information , meta={'item': item} , dont_filter=True)
        yield request

# Need to check for some empty values : almost done
def seller_information(self,  response):
    item = response.request.meta['item']
    item['seller_name'] = response.xpath('//h1[contains(@id , "sellerName")]/text()').extract()
    yield item
```

Please i tried so many solutions to make a request response in loop, but always the item takes only one value randomly instead of list. Normally the item of sellers name should be a list. Thanks for any help

Comment: Where variable name come from?

Comment: it contains a couple of links i get it through a scrapy request it gets what it has to get, the problem started from the loop for.

Comment: Please, paste the entire spider code and an example of the output log.